# How do I keep MS Word application hidden using python when searching through more than one document?

Tags: python, ms-word, visible, win32com

I am working on a project that needs to extract information from several files in a directory.  It works, except when it goes into a new document, MS Word flashes on the page.  I'm using win32com.client and set the .Visible to false but I still get a flash of each file the program opens.

wordapp is a global variable

```
wordapp = win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')
wordapp.Visible = False

for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".docx") or files.endswith('.doc'):
            WordtxtExtract(files, 1);
```

... in WordtxtExtract ...

```
wordapp.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath(DataFile))

doc = wordapp.ActiveDocument

for TableCnt in range(1, doc.Tables.Count):
    DataFromTables(PrgDataCollection, doc, TableCnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while trying to use a method I made to insert text into a Word Doc with a for loop. It seems if the file is already open in word although the wordapp itself is not visible when the for loop iterates over the wordapp.Documents.Open again after the file is already opened the wordapp becomes visible. Use the Following in your **init** of your WordtxtExtract Method.

```
    if self.wordApp.Documents.Count < 1:
        self.doc = self.wordApp.Documents.Open(self.path)
        print('opened doc')
    else:
        self.doc = self.wordApp.ActiveDocument
        print('Did not open doc')
```

That worked for my situation at least and it was very similar to yours. I Hope this helps someone cause I searched, and racked my brain for hours to solve this one.

Note: If you have another word doc open it will grab that one as the active doc.